# Change the color of the numbers in the table based on their value by js

Tags: javascript

I have 2 tables and the numbers in each table change automatically, and I want the numbers in Table 1 to change their background color if they match any of the numbers in Table 2.
My code changes the background color of numbers, but the color only changes one item.
Friends, can you help me how to solve this problem?

```js
setInterval(() => {

  const tds =document.querySelector("table").querySelectorAll("tr")[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)+0].querySelectorAll("td");

  tds.forEach((item) => {
    item.innerHTML = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+0);
  });
  
  $(function(){
    $(".table2 tr td").each(function() {
      var val = parseInt(this.innerHTML);
       $(".table1 tr td").each(function() {
          var val2 = parseInt(this.innerHTML);
          if (val2 == val) {
             this.style.backgroundColor = "#F00000"
          }else{
             this.style.backgroundColor = "#fff"
          }
        });
    });
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
table tr td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table{
  width:40%;
  font-weight:bold ;
  font-size:13px;
  text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Table 1:
<table class="table1" >
       
        <tr>
             <td>21</td>
             <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>22</td>
             <td>22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>32</td>
             <td>32</td>
        </tr>           
</table>
</div>
<br>
<div>Table 2:
<table class="table2" >
        <tr>
             <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>6</td>
        </tr>           
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the numbers from the second table in an array and see if it contains the generated value in the first table when you loop through it :

```
  const nums = [...document.querySelector(".table2").querySelectorAll("td")].map(e => +e.innerText);
```

```js
setInterval(() => {

  const tds = document.querySelector("table").querySelectorAll("tr")[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 0].querySelectorAll("td");

  tds.forEach((item) => {
    item.innerHTML = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 0);
  });

  const nums = [...document.querySelector(".table2").querySelectorAll("td")].map(e => +e.innerText);

  $(function() {

    $(".table1 tr td").each(function() {
      var val2 = parseInt(this.innerHTML);

      if (nums.includes(val2)) {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "#F00000"
      } else {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "#fff"
      }
    });
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  width: 40%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Table 1:
  <table class="table1">

    <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>32</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<br>
<div>Table 2:
  <table class="table2">
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```